# css stylelint rule to catch 'selector is expected' error

Tags: css, stylelint

As part of my process I use stylelint to look for css errors before build and deploy for our site. However someone checked in the following which fails on the css parser / minifier but passed stylelint.

```
.example-class ,
/*.example-class-two span*/ {
..... removed for brevity ..... 
}
```

I can't seem to figure out any existing rule to enable to catch this. Is there one that I am missing? Otherwise, is it time to write a custom rule to catch this?

Comment: don't you want to move coma to the next line inside comment block?

Comment: yes exactly, this was a mistake, my issue is that is was not caught by the stylelint. I want to make sure to catch errors like this.

Comment: I didn't use stylelint, but csslint catch this fine - http://csslint.net

Comment: Thanks, maybe its time to swap over to csslint. I will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to write this rule [as a plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins/#writing-plugins). stylelint used to have a rule `selector-no-empty` that handled your use case, but it was removed in version 7.8.0. You could use the rule as the starting point for a plugin. [Here's the source](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/7.7.1/lib/rules/selector-no-empty/index.js).

Note that the rule was originally removed for [the following reason](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/0c27c3ba92bf1b34d9e50af497ad4efa654f5a67/CHANGELOG.md#780):

> It is beyond the scope of stylelint's core package to effectively validate against the CSS spec. Please investigate csstree and css-values for this functionality, and contribute to those projects and to stylelint plugins wrapping them.

There is currently a [csstree stylelint plugin](https://github.com/csstree/stylelint-validator) for checking the validity of your CSS, but [selector validation is not ready yet](https://github.com/csstree/stylelint-validator/issues/13#issuecomment-332497214). So you could just use the csstree stylelint plugin and wait for selector validation to land.

stylelint itself is not a CSS specification validator, it's designed more to detect code that might, despite being valid, have unintended consequences - with rules like `declaration-block-no-shorthand-property-overrides`, `no-descending-specificity`, `no-duplicate-selectors` etc.

Or to limit what CSS features can and can’t be used within a code base by a team - with rules like `unit-blacklist`, `selector-max-id`, `selector-class-pattern` etc.